# ngx-bootstrap - Timepicker popup for input

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using the `time-picker` component from [ngx-bootsrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/timepicker) and I want to include the `time-picker` to an input box as follows. (More in a popup dialog way, which used in [date-picker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker))

[image]

Any advice on how to do that , because as per the documentation it always uses the `time-picker` HTML directive.

```
eg:- <timepicker [(ngModel)]="mytime"></timepicker>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use popover to achieve this.

I have created a example for this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-ngx-timepicker

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: In the case where you want to be able to edit the time in addition to having it display as a time-only format, how would you do it? I tried the following and am getting errors: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-ngx-timepicker-jkdemj ; the change being `<input [ngModel]="mytime | date:'hh:mm aa'" (ngModelChange)="mytime=$event" [popover]="popTemplate" [outsideClick]="true" placement="bottom" />`

Answer (score 5):

@aspergillusOryzae: to display time-only format, use `value` properties instead of `[(ngModel)]`

```
<input value="{{ mytime | date: 'HH:mm' }}" [popover]="popTemplate" [outsideClick]="true" placement="bottom" />
```

Comment: it eliminates the modelling, events and date conversion for getting value in input of 'HH:mm' format. Thanks.