# How to use ngx-bootstrap time picker?

Tags: angular, timepicker

I am using Angular 9 & ngx-bootstrap 5.6.1.
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/timepicker?tab=overview#form
Here is my component code:

```
export class TournamentCreationComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.tournamentTypeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          ...
          tournamentStartTime: new FormControl(),
          ...    
        }); 
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is my template:

```
    <form  [formGroup]="tournamentTypeForm" (ngSubmit)="template(tournamentTypeForm.value)"> 
    <div class="content">
    <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="tournamentStartTime" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Start Time</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
         <ng-template #popTemplate>
            <timepicker [(ngModel)]="tournamentStartTime" [showMeridian]="true"></timepicker>
          </ng-template>
          <input [(ngModel)]="tournamentStartTime"  [popover]="popTemplate" 
                 [outsideClick]="true" placement="bottom"  class="form-control"/>                   
      </div>               
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

I am  getting this error:

```
ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:
  
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});

  Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:

  Example:

  
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
   <input formControlName="firstName">
   <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</div>

at Function.modelParentException (forms.js:6653)
at NgModel._checkParentType (forms.js:7086)
at NgModel._checkForErrors (forms.js:7072)
at NgModel.ngOnChanges (forms.js:6967)
at NgModel.wrapOnChangesHook_inPreviousChangesStorage (core.js:27137)
at callHook (core.js:4739)
at callHooks (core.js:4699)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4639)
at refreshView (core.js:11963)
at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13335)
```

From this error message I understand because my tournamentStartTime is a form control, part of a form group it is not working.
I tried to replace [(ngModel)] with formControlName at both places. If I do that, errors in the console go away, but the time picker's time does not get captured in the input field.

Comment: Why do you need to bind same property to multiple form controls? What's the use case? Can user enter time in `input`? and you want it to reflect in `timepicker`? timepicker takes a date instance, how will you be adding date via text `input`?

Comment: @Siddhant, I am also using date picker in the same form. In absence of a combined date & time picker, I want to use the date from date picker & take only the time part of the time picker & set to the date. Time picker gives you whatever time you choose with today's date.

Comment: Though I do understand that you are trying to implement combined date & time picker, I am still unable to understand why do you need an additional `input` element --> `<input [(ngModel)]="tournamentStartTime"  [popover]="popTemplate" 
                 [outsideClick]="true" placement="bottom"  class="form-control"/> `  User can select the time in `timepicker`, what's the use of having an additional `input` with a popover displaying `timepicker`. Can user input time in `input` too?

Comment: @Siddhant,  pl refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054178/ngx-bootstrap-timepicker-popup-for-input. Still I cannot make it work